# Problem with SQLite & Qt

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite, casting

This is the code which has problem:

```c++
QMessageBox::information(this, "Connexion Open", "Connexion BD Ok!");
QSqlQuery req;
req.exec("SELECT * FROM reservation");
while(req.next()) {
    float id = req.value(0).toFloat();
    text2->setText("  "+QString::number(id)+" " );
```

The message "Connexion BD Ok!" appears perfectly.
How can I retrieve the result of the DB knowing that the DBMS(SGBD) is SQLite?

Thank You

Comment: You are already retrieving the result of the query in the `while` loop. What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are already retrieving the id, so I'm guessing that your question is how you connect to a sqlite database in the first place with Qt. You typically specify the database when you are connecting. Something like:

```
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase(ntr("QSQLITE"));
QFileInfo dbPath(pathToDb, dbFileName);
db.setDatabaseName(dbPath.absoluteFilePath());

if (!db.open()) {
    qDebug() << ntr("Could not open database:") << db.databaseName();
}
if (db.isOpenError()) {
    QSqlError err = db.lastError();
    qDebug() << ntr("Last error:") << err.text();
}
```